# Using class member variable as reference

Tags: c++, reference, stdmap

I would like to have a class member variable to be able to switch in between items in a map so that when it is modified, the content of the map is also modified.

Is there any way other than to use a pointer to the content of the map ? Old code only needed only variable, now the new one needs to switch. If I change the variable type, then all functions using this member variable need to be changed. Not complicated, but I would find it ugly to have * in front of it everywhere...

A reference variable cannot be rebound, so how can I achieve this ?

```
class A
{
    std::map<std::string,std::vector<int>> mMyMap;
    std::vector<int>& mCurrentVector;
    std::vector<int>* mCurrentVectorPointer;
    std::vector<int> mDefaultVector;

    void setCurrentVector(int iKey);
    void addToCurrentVector(int iValue);
}


A::A():
mDefaultVector(std::vector<int>())
mCurrentVector(mDefaultVector)
{
    mMyMap["key1"] = std::vector<int>(1,1);
    mMyMap["key2"] = std::vector<int>(1,2);
    mCurrentVectorPointer = &mMyMap[0];
}

A::setCurrentVector(std::string iKey)
{
    if(mMyMap.find(iKey) != mMyMap.end())
    {
        mCurrentVector = mMyMap[iKey]; //can't change a reference...
        mCurrentVectorPointer = &mMyMap[iKey]; //could use pointer, but
    }
}

A::addToCurrentVector(int iValue)
{
    mCurrentVector.push_back(iValue);
    //or
    (*mCurrentVectorPointer).push_back(iValue);
    //
    mCurrentVectorPointer->push_back(iValue);
}


void main()
{
    A wClassA();
    wClassA.setCurrentVector("key2");
    wClassA.addToCurrentVector(3);
    wClassA.setCurrentVector("key1");
    wClassA.addToCurrentVector(4);
}
```

mMyMap["key1"] now contains 1,4

mMyMap["key2"] now contains 2,3

Comment: Save the current key and use `mMyMap[currentKey].push_back(iValue)` in the add function.

Comment: Smash, that example code is so full of mistakes it's more a distraction than a clarification.

Comment: Just use the vector and use operator ->. *mCurrentVectorPointer.push_back is a syntax error! The other solution is to create a vector_view that would emulate the vector interface, unfortunately, the dot operator did not make it in c++17, it would be longer to implement than switching to the pointer alternative!

Comment: why mCurrentVector = mMyMap[0] and not mMyMap[iKey] ?

Comment: Sitting in the Bo Persson camp until it's demonstrated that the repeated look-up is too slow. If it is found to be too slow, use the pointer or wrap the pointer so it looks like a reference.

Comment: I would recommend using the value of a key instead of a pointer or a reference. Instead of `std::vector<int>& mCurrentVector;` use `std::string mCurrentKey;`.

Comment: All good comments, just wanted to make sure there wasn't a way to just modify the value of the mCurrentVector variable (which is used everywhere) so that the switching between vectors was transparent to the rest of the code. Point is to have the least amount of code to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reseat a reference once it has been assigned which means you are left with using your other option, a pointer.

As I understand it, you're refactoring some existing code which only used a single vector, whereas now you need a map of vectors.

You're trying to achieve this with minimal modifications, and keeping the interface to the vector the same.

An option would be to use a *local reference*, assigned from your pointer.

```
class A
{
    using Vector = std::vector<int>;
public:
    A()
    {
        map_["key1"] = std::vector<int>(1,1);
        map_["key2"] = std::vector<int>(1,2);
        curr_vec_ = &map_["key1"];
    }

    void setCurrentVector(const std::string& key)
    {
        if(map_.find(key) != map_.end())
        {
            curr_vec_ = &map_[key]; 
        }
    }

    void addToCurrentVector(int val)
    {
        assert(curr_vec_);
        Vector& curr_vec = *curr_vec_; // local reference

        curr_vec.push_back(val);

        curr_vec[0] = 2;
        // etc
    }

private:
    std::map<std::string, Vector> map_;
    Vector* curr_vec_ = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Yes, as mentionned I had thought about this idea, but this gets ugly quickly  and requires a lot of code changes, i.e.: when you need to access the [] operator `(*curr_vec_)[0]` instead of `curr_vec_[0]`, etc.

Comment: @Smash an option would be to use a local reference then. I've updated my answer

Comment: Good idea, but the code uses a member variable for the vector, so I would need to use the local reference in each function, pretty similar scope of changes, I'll give it some thought if there is no other solution

Answer (score 0):

You may write some wrapper:

```
#define Return(X) noexcept(noexcept(X)) -> decltype(X) { return X; }


template <typename U>
class MyVectorRef
{
private:
    std::vector<U>* vec = nullptr;
public:
    explicit MyVectorRef(std::vector<U>& v) : vec(&v) {}

    void reset(std::vector<U>& v) {vec = &v;}

    // vector interface
    auto at(std::size_t i) const Return(vec->at(i))
    auto at(std::size_t i)  Return(vec->at(i))
    auto operator [](std::size_t i) const Return(vec->operator[](i))
    auto operator [](std::size_t i) Return(vec->operator[](i))

    template <typename ... Ts> auto assign(Ts&&... ts) Return(vec->assign(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...))
    auto assign( std::initializer_list<U> ilist ) Return(vec->assign(ilist))
    template <typename T> auto push_back(T&& t) const Return(vec->push_back(std::forward<T>(t)))
    template <typename T> auto emplace_back(T&& t) const Return(vec->emplace_back(std::forward<T>(t)))

    auto begin() const Return(vec->begin())
    auto begin() Return(vec->begin())
    auto end() const Return(vec->end())
    auto end() Return(vec->end())
    auto cbegin() const Return(vec->cbegin())
    auto cend() const Return(vec->cend())
    // ...
};
```

and then, use it:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : mCurrentVector(mDefaultVector) {
        mMyMap["key1"] = std::vector<int>(1,1);
        mMyMap["key2"] = std::vector<int>(1,2);
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> mMyMap;
    std::vector<int> mDefaultVector;
    MyVectorRef<int> mCurrentVector;

    void setCurrentVector(std::string iKey)
    {
        auto it = mMyMap.find(iKey);
        if (it != mMyMap.end())
        {
            mCurrentVector.reset(it->second);
        }
    }
    void addToCurrentVector(int iValue)
    {
        mCurrentVector.push_back(iValue);
    }

};
```

But I think it would be simpler to just create a getter in `A` and use directly a pointer:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() : mCurrentVector(&mDefaultVector) {
        mMyMap["key1"] = std::vector<int>(1,1);
        mMyMap["key2"] = std::vector<int>(1,2);
    }

    std::map<std::string, std::vector<int>> mMyMap;
    std::vector<int> mDefaultVector;
    std::vector<int>* mCurrentVector;

    std::vector<int>& GeCurrentVector() { return *mCurrentVector; }

    void setCurrentVector(std::string iKey)
    {
        auto it = mMyMap.find(iKey);
        if (it != mMyMap.end())
        {
            mCurrentVector = &it->second;
        }
    }
    void addToCurrentVector(int iValue)
    {
        GeCurrentVector().push_back(iValue);
    }

};
```

Comment: For more transparency, add `noexcept(noexcept(X))` to your macro.

Comment: @aschepler: Added.